# Xamarin C#: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, xamarin

I need consume a WebService(SOAP) in a Xamarin.Forms APP. I import the webService as "Service Reference" in PCL.

Then i call the webService as:

```
  //...oncreate
    Guid g1 = new Guid("3f0c9ec7-9382-403d-8480-7142a7fd65d9");
    ws.GetNotificacionesAsync(g1);
    ws.GetNotificacionesCompleted += ws_GetNotificacionesCompleted;

void ws_GetNotificacionesCompleted(object sender, WSPuentesUsuario.GetNotificacionesCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                int a = 12;
            }
```

Finally, "e" show this error: `Result = System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

(`int a = 12;` is only used to breakpoint)
PD: I use this link how example
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/

Comment: this is usually an exception on the server - look at the InnerException to see if that gives you a clearer idea what went wrong

Comment: Thanks for your response Jason, but: how can I see the InnerException?

Comment: use the debugger - it will be a property on the TargetInvocationException

Comment: I try with: 
while (e.InnerException != null) e = e.InnerException;
and GetNotificacionesCompletedEventArgs does not contain a definition from InnerException.

Comment: InnerException is a property of Exception, not EventArgs.  Use a try catch block to explicitly capture the exception, or use the debugger to examine the exception when it is thrown

Comment: Does not generated Exception on try catch block.<br/> <pre>
try
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                WSUsuario.UsuarioWSSoapClient usc = new WSUsuario.UsuarioWSSoapClient();
                usc.LoginAsync("user", "pass");
                usc.LoginCompleted += usc_LoginCompleted;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);

            }<code>

Comment: The error: {System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException}
InnerException = {System.Net.WebException}

Comment: Look at the message on the InnerException - it should tell you something about the cause of the error on the webserver.  From there you may need to look at the server logs and code to figure out the issue

Comment: @Jason I send you a mail with details. Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Xamarin Android need to comunicate the HttpGet and HttpPost protocols. These protocols must be generated on SideServer.  Adds protocols this form:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yx7be39(v=vs.100).aspx

Finally:
System.reflexion.Exception can be caused by a null response from server.(Incorrect protocols)

PD: Remember use the browser on emulator/device to see the correct navegation to webService(link webService), also remember that localhost is a invalid link to device/emulator.