# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in xamarin with web service

Tags: web-services, xamarin.android

I'm new in xamarin, I used web service (asmx) with xamarin and I got it on error follow:
Erreur :[image]

MainActivity : [image]

web service : [image]
web.config : [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The System.reflexion.Exception may be caused by a null response from server, please check the InnerException value. You'll be able to get the details about the exception from the InnerExcpeption. Related link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244722/xamarin-c-system-reflection-targetinvocationexception/28345484

Comment: Thanks for your response y3z1,already done https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8UKw.png ,please can you explain more ?

Comment: Not the web.config, please check the details about InnerException. Similar issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104547/exception-when-using-e-result-in-xamarin-forms